# Define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\circ f(n) = \text{number of positive divisors of } n$. Show that $f(p)$ is prime if $p$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\circ f(n) = \text{number of positive divisors of } n$. Show that $f(p)$ is prime if $p$ is prime.

It can be seen that if $f(f(n))$ is written as $\tau(n)$ for simplicity, then composition (thrice) on $f$ yields us $\tau(f(n)) = f(\tau(n))$. If $n$ is a prime, we get $\tau(f(p)) = f(\tau (p)) = f(2)$. If we can show that $f(2) = 2$ we will be done as $\tau(f(p))=2$ directly implies that $f(p)$ is prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My bad, I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your equation tells us $\tau(f(2))=f(2)$, so if $f(2)=x$, then $x$ has $x$ factors. In other words, every positive integer up to $x$ is a factor of $x$, so $x=1$ or $2$.

If $x=1$, we have $f(f(2)) = \tau(2) = 2$, so $f(1) = 2$. Also, $\tau (f(p)) = f(2) = 1$ for all $p$, implying $f(p) = 1$ for all primes $p$. Now if $f(n)$ ever takes a prime value where $n \neq 1$, we have $f(f(n)) = f(p) = 1$, which means $n$ has $1$ factor, which is impossible. So $f(n)$ is not ever prime. But simply take $f(f(4)) = 3$ which is prime. This is a contradiction.

So $x \neq 1$, giving $x = 2$ and we are done.